# How to fetch data from pokeapi using UseEffect in React with a url from a previously fetched JSON?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So basically, I have already figured out how to fetch a JSON from the pokeAPI that looks something like this, for the first 9 pokemon, and have been able to render the names of the pokemon in a grid.

```
[
    {
        "name": "bulbasaur",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
    },
    {
        "name": "ivysaur",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
    },
    {
        "name": "venusaur",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"
    },
    {
        "name": "charmander",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"
    },
    {
        "name": "charmeleon",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/"
    },
    {
        "name": "charizard",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"
    },
    {
        "name": "squirtle",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/"
    },
    {
        "name": "wartortle",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/"
    },
    {
        "name": "blastoise",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/"
    }
]
```

Here is the custom hook I have used to call the api, and also the component that uses the hook,

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function useFetch(url){
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const dataFetchedRef = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(dataFetchedRef.current) return;
        dataFetchedRef.current = true;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(url);
                const json = await res.json();
                setData(json.results);
                setIsLoading(res);
            } catch(e) {
                setIsError(e);
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [dataFetchedRef]);

    console.log(data); 
    return [data, isLoading, isError];
}

export default useFetch;
```

```
export function PokeCard() {

    const [pokemons, isLoading, isError] = useFetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=9');

return (
    <Grid container spacing={4} className='poke-cards'>
        {pokemons.map((pokemon, index) => (
        <Grid item xs={8} sm={6} md={4} lg={2}>
            <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }} key={pokemon.name}>
                <CardMedia
                    sx={{ height: 140 }}
                    image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
                    title={("green iguana")}
                />
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                    {pokemon.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                    Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
                    species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small">Share</Button>
                    <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
);

}
```

What I am trying to do, is get the urls from the first useFetch, and use them to call the api again using the 'url' from the first retrieved json, stored in pokemons in the PokeCard component, but I have no idea what I should do, I cannot put the hook call in a loop to dynamically retrieve the information to put into poke-cards.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I guess we need to rename the component as its name is not reflective of what it's rendering. It's more like `PokeList`. Then you can create a `PokeCard` which basically accepts whatever data is needed. Inside each PokeCard you can call your API just as you did here and render it. So basically, you'd need to render `PokeCard`s in your map and then each PokeCard will be responsible to fetch its own data based on some props.